# PM2 with application arguments on restart only

Tags: arguments, pm2, restart

I would like to use pm2 with 2 different scenarios, the first start of the app without any arguments.
Any restart of the app after crash with an argument.

```
pm2 start myapp
```

and if the app crashes it should run with an argument

```
myapp --myargument
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Curcuma_ Unfortunately no :(

Comment: I asked the same on their GitHub issues. It seems they are focused on other stuff